# Wiremock how to return value in response from the request when the request key has dot

Tags: wiremock, wiremock-standalone

I have a request body in json with some keys having dot (.) in the name. ( i.e. get John Doe)

```
{
  "details":{
  "full.name":"John Doe", 
  "age":30, 
  "city":"Boston"
  }
}
```

In the stub definition I have:

```
{
  "request":{
    "urlPath":"/path",
    "method":"ANY"
   },
  "response":{
     "body":"{{jsonbody response.body '$.details.[full.name]'}}"
  }
}
```

stub gets created but I get this error when I hit it:

`Error 500 wiremock.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedException: wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.HandlebarsException: inline@26d6cbba:1:3: count not find helper: &apos;jsonpath&apos;...`.

I tried escaping **[]** around full.name with **\** , **** and **%5B%5D** still no luck.
What is the current syntax.

Wiremock 2.33

Comment: did you try to put single quotes around `full.name`?

Comment: yes, still the same issue

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got this working.

jsonPath can work with both . notation and [] notation.
Since here . is the part of keyname I used [] to avoid confusing wiremock.
Following stub gives me desired result:

```
{
  "request":{
    "urlPath":"/path",
    "method":"ANY"
   },
  "response":{
     "body":"{{jsonbody response.body \"$['details']['full.name']\"}}"
  }
}
```

Comment: it is request.body also it is not working.